# microsoft word document open hangs on server but works in development

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I,m writing web service  using c# for replacing word bookmarks.

Following code works in development but not works in windows server.

Can't open word  in following line

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref CopyOfTemplate, ref confirmConversions, ref readOnly, ref addToRecentFiles, ref passwordDoc, ref passwordTemplate, ref revert, ref writepwdoc, ref writepwTemplate, ref format, ref encoding, ref visible, ref openRepair, ref docDirection, ref notEncoding, ref xmlTransform);
```

Word version in both environment is 2013.

In server I see the started word process on task, but it freezes. CPU 0%.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

                wordApp.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsMessageBox;

                // wordApp.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;

                wordApp.Visible = true;
                object confirmConversions = Type.Missing; object readOnly = Type.Missing; object addToRecentFiles = Type.Missing; object passwordDoc = Type.Missing; object passwordTemplate = Type.Missing; object revert = Type.Missing; object writepwdoc = Type.Missing; object writepwTemplate = Type.Missing; object format = Type.Missing; object encoding = Type.Missing; object visible = Type.Missing;
                object openRepair = Type.Missing;
                object docDirection = Type.Missing; object notEncoding = Type.Missing; object xmlTransform = Type.Missing;

                if (!File.Exists(CopyOfTemplate.ToString()))
                {
                    throw new Exception("template does not exists ");
                }
                File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(Settings.RealFilePath, "log.txt"), "\r\n before open;CopyOfTemplate="+ CopyOfTemplate);




                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref CopyOfTemplate, ref confirmConversions, ref readOnly, ref addToRecentFiles, ref passwordDoc, ref passwordTemplate, ref revert, ref writepwdoc, ref writepwTemplate, ref format, ref encoding, ref visible, ref openRepair, ref docDirection, ref notEncoding, ref xmlTransform);
```

Comment: I highly recommend you read https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office before proceding. Server-side use of Office applications is not supported. Given the problem description my first suspicion is that Word is displaying a dialog box and is waiting for user-input to dismiss it. The recommended way to work with Word documents in a server environment is to leverage the Word Open XML file format on the closed file, rather than automating the Word application.

Comment: Agree with the above, if you are working with DocX files, you don't actually need to automate MS Word, there are nuget packages which work directly with the file - https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocX/

Comment: As pointed out in the comments, it's not advised to use Word Interop on server side. There are alternatives like [Open XML SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) for low-level manipulation and [GemBox.Document](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GemBox.Document/) for high-level manipulation.